# 1C Предприятие

Tags: книги, 1с

Друзья, жизнь заставила учить 1С и даже не 8ку, а 7ку. Никак не могу найти приличное чтиво либо видео курсы либо какой то самоучитель, попадаются либо шлак либо сразу про 8ку. Очень прошу, подскажите, где можно раздобыть материал для самообучения. Спасибо.

Comment: В сети очень много информации. Далее: Вам требуется справка по встроенному языку программирования или просто работа с конфигурацией? Файл - сервер, клиент - сервер, терминал? Очень много ньюансов в С-ке :)

Comment: Набрать в интернете FAQ1C V77.
И во всех конкретных запросах в Гугле или Яндексе добавлять "1C V7" или "1C V77"

Comment: В семерке без 1С++ сложно программировать вот тебе ссылочка http://infostart.ru/public/15540/

Answer (score 1):

В учебном центре есть [дистанционные курсы](http://www.1c-uc3.ru/name-do.html). Ну и другая информация там есть. В крайнем случае телефон там есть, может что-то посоветуют.
По 7ке сейчас довольно сложно найти что-либо, если удастся найти книжки, которые идут с коробкой (по крайней мере раньше такие давали, как минимум франчайзям), то их в принципе должно хватить для самообучения...

ЗЫ Да, халявы скорее всего не будет.

Comment: Хотя вроде гуглится и 7ка, правда что там внутри не знаю, может и шлак тот самый...

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте ЕСИС - Единая Справочная Информационная Система.
Да сайт вот неплохой: http://help1c.com/
Вот у себя нашел: http://rusfolder.com/33179300